# What does this error mean: 'list' object has no attribute 'state'

Tags: python, python-3.x

> 'list' object has no attribute 'state'

```
def a_star_search(self,goal_state,h_function):
    global current
    nexts=[self]
    poped=0
    max_nodes=1

    depth_next=[0]
    pathcost_next=[0]
    visited= set([])       
    while nexts:
        if len(nexts)> max_nodes:
             max_nodes=len( nexts)
             current = nexts.pop(0)
             poped +=1
             current_depth=depth_next.pop(0)
             current_pathcost= pathcost_next.pop(0)
             visited.add(tuple(current.state.reshape(1,9)[0]))
        if np.array_equal(current.state,goal_state):
            current.path()
```

Comment: You have `current.state` on your second and third last line of code but from the error we can see that `current` is a list and it does not contain an attribute `state`

Comment: you can find all the legit attributes [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)